# How to limit the characters (to show in tree view) of text field in odoo

Tags: treeview, odoo, textfield

I have a text field.

```
description = fields.Text('Description')
```

I want to show this field in tree view, but not the whole value of the field.
I mean if my field value is "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", I just want to show
"AAA..." in tree view.

How to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Please use the below xml code for the field

```
xml : <tree string="Tree String" class="my_class"> <field name="description" />
```

in css write  below:

```
css : .my_class [data-id="description"]{width: 200px;}
```

Comment: Do I have to add this in __openerp__.py

Comment: Which odoo version you are using?

Comment: You have to add the class in xml file and add css file in the same module

Comment: I'm on version 7. Thanks I will try.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a computed field to render just a few characters from the "description" field, and expose it in the tree view (as read-only)